# How can remove a specific number from input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove a specific number from a input value.
Example:

When the user click on a button with a number, I will need to remove with Jquery or Javascript that number from the input.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thank you.

```
<input name="boxesnumbers" value="5 3 1">
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(3)">3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(5)">5</a>
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(1)">1</a>
```

Comment: weird you are treating links like checkboxes.

Comment: You can use jQuery or Javascript to access the attributes of your `input` element. Just look it up in the online documentation for jQuery or Javascript. For example, just do a web search on "jquery change input value".

Comment: So read the value, split it into numbers, add or remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
function removethis(number) {
  let box = document.getElementById("boxesnumbers");
  let regexp = new RegExp(`\\b${number}\\b`,"g");
  let newValue = box.value.replace(regexp,"");
  box.value = newValue;
}
```

The regular expression will make sure you only remove full numbers from the list of values, so if you have "2 12" and click on 2, it will only remove the 2 value and not the 12.

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello suggested:

```js
let removethis = num =>
  document.querySelector('input').value =
    document.querySelector('input').value
      .split(' ')
      .filter(v => v != num)
      .join(' ');
```

```html
<input name="boxesnumbers" value="5 3 1">
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(3)">3</a>
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(5)">5</a>
<a href="#" onclick="removethis(1)">1</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<input name="boxesnumbers" value="5 3 1">
<a href="#" >3</a>
<a href="#" >5</a>
<a href="#" >1</a>
<script>
$('a').click(function() {
$('[name="boxesnumbers"]').val($('[name="boxesnumbers"]').val().replace($(this).text(), ''))

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend refactoring your existing code to not use inline `onclick` attributes.

A more elegant way to accomplish this would be to give each link a `data-remove` attribute, then reference this value in an event listener, rather than in a hard-coded handler call. The result is more organized, comprehensible code which also allows you to modify `removethis` or disable certain links without changing the HTML, should you need to do this.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("input[name='boxesnumbers']");

// Define the removal function with a string argument.
function removethis(n) {
  let val = elem.value;      /* Store the initial value of the input element. */
  elem.value = val
    .split(/\s/g)            /* Split the string value by spaces. */
    .filter(i => i !== n)    /* Discard the numbers that are equal to the argument value. */
    .join(" ");              /* Recombine the list of numbers into a space-delimited string. */
}

const btn = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

// Create a global click listener.
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('a[data-remove]')) {    /* If the element is a removal link... */
    removethis(e.target.dataset.remove);       /* Call removethis with the data-remove attribute. */
  }
});
```

```html
<input name="boxesnumbers" value="5 3 1">
<a href="#" data-remove="3">3</a>
<a href="#" data-remove="5">5</a>
<a href="#" data-remove="1">1</a>
```